# Pasting data in multiple cursor mode

Tags: visual-studio-code

in vs code I have the following file

```
1
2
3

a
b
c
```

Now I do the following steps

1. cut the lines a b c.
2. select the lines 1, 2, 3 and then go into multiple cursor mode (shift, alt I).
3. go to the end of the each number press and type a , and then do a paste.

The result is

```
1, a
b
c
2, a
b
c
3, a
b
c
```

but the result I wanted is

```
1, a
2, b
3, c
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

*Check out Mark's good answer as well. There have been some updates to VS Code he mentions that should be considered as well.*

Using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>, you need to cut the text in multiple cursor mode as well:

<kbd>1</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd><kbd>3</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd><kbd>b</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd><kbd>c</kbd>

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd><kbd>↑</kbd>

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>

<kbd>↑</kbd><kbd>↑</kbd><kbd>↑</kbd><kbd>↑</kbd><kbd>→</kbd>

<kbd>,</kbd>

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>

[image]

**As of the [1.23.1 April update](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_23#_column-selection-using-middle-mouse-button), a more convenient, middle mouse button selection can be used.**

With the cursor and keyboard, 
Instead of cutting the lines like normal, select from the end of the cursor to the beginning while in multi-cursor mode while holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>. After cutting the text with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, select with multiple cursors again by holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>. Then, type <kbd>,</kbd>  and paste with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> like you described.

[image]

You can also use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> and the direction arrows to select with multiple cursors,

[image: keyboard demo]

Answer (score 12):

Sometime ago this functionality was apparently added.  You can simply cut to your clipboard and then paste to multiple cursors - and, if there are the same number of lines on the clipboard as multiple cursors - each cursor will get one line from the clipboard.

You no longer need to be in multi-cursor mode for the cut or however you got the text onto the clipboard.
Just cut it.

Demo:

[image: multicursor paste spread]

Unfortunately, the gif cut off the full command after selecting the `1,2,3,`.  What you then want to do is put a cursor at the end of each line of the selection.  Command: `Add Cursors to Line Ends` <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>.

VSCode 1.39 added this setting:

> Editor: Multi Cursor Paste
>
> Controls pasting when the line count of the pasted text matches the
> cursor count.

`"editor.multiCursorPaste": "spread"`

that will do what you want.

There is a second option `full` where each cursor will get the entire clipboard text.  See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_39.md#new-option-for-multi-cursor-pasting.   Demo of the `full` option:

[image: demo of mulit-cursor paste full option]

From the [multi-cursor paste release notes](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_39.md#new-option-for-multi-cursor-pasting):

> **New option for multi cursor pasting**
>
> In the past, when pasting multi-line text from the clipboard, VS Code
> would check if the clipboard text line count matches the cursor count,
> and if it does, it would "distribute"/"spread" each line to a cursor.
> This behavior is now tunable via the editor.multiCursorPaste setting,
> which can have the values:

```
spread - Each cursor pastes a line of text (default).

full - Each cursor pastes the full clipboard text.
```

Comment: Thanks! Any idea how to temp toggle to the other paste type?

Comment: You could look at the toggle extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rebornix.toggle

Comment: In the gif animation, after highlighting "1 2 3" the key command is [Shift]+[Ctrl]+[l], followed by [,], followed by [Ctrl]+[v]

Comment: @Adrian I edited the answer because I see the gif didn't catch the last keystroke.  It is `Shift+Alt+I`.   Add cursors to the line ends of the selection.

Comment: i got this issue on today with `Version: 1.79.0-insider (Universal)` and still not working .