# Why isn't pasting data in multiple cursor mode working in VS Code 1.79 Insiders?

Tags: visual-studio-code

this question very similar like on [Pasting data in multiple cursor mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49073666/pasting-data-in-multiple-cursor-mode) but i still on issue/problem.

here is my engine

```
Version: 1.79.0-insider (Universal)
Commit: 70dcd62d397867fe03626f938139b834950a985c
Date: 2023-05-03T22:56:33.784Z
Electron: 22.4.8
Chromium: 108.0.5359.215
Node.js: 16.17.1
V8: 10.8.168.25-electron.0
OS: Darwin arm64 22.3.0
Sandboxed: Yes
```

A). i hope with imgur can more describe what my issue .

case 1 (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vn3Pt.jpg)

case 2 (https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vBhx.jpg)

I don't have a windows , so i can only describe on mac version.

B). here is the issue describe by text
on my vscode i have code like these

```
const new_data = 'test'

hello_here
you_here
```

i have copied the word of test then i use `command + option + arrow down ( ⌘ + ⌥ + ⬇ )` on `_here` txt. ( on bottombar UI of vscode ) its defined 2 selections .

so its look like these

```
hello_|here
you_|here
```

`|` its just my cursor , then i tried paste by ( ⌘ + v ).

the result is

```
hello_testhere
you_|here
```

what i expected is

```
hello_testhere
you_testhere
```

here is my keyboard setting filter by `paste` ( i never change anything )

```
Command

Notebook: Paste Cell Above notebook.cell.pasteAbove ⬆ ⌘ V

Paste editor.action.clipboardPasteAction ⌘ V

Terminal: Paste into Active Terminal workbench.action.terminal.paste  ⌘ V

editor. changePasteType ⌘ .

execPaste ⌘ V

filesExplorer .paste ⌘ V
```

1. already disable all extension of my vscode
2. delete all my setting.json ( user / system )
3. restart my laptop

Comment: why create a new question with almost identical text if you can also **EDIT** your original question and add a comment with `@name` for the people you want to be notified of the edit

Comment: Just so you know, deleting a poorly received post will contribute towards [a question ban](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255583/11107541). That's why (if you don't want a question ban,) you _should_ edit questions instead of deleting and reposting them.

Comment: also, I hope you can see now (now that I've answer this question) that your previous question _really was_ missing important details, and that I was genuinely trying to help by asking so many clarifying questions and caring about specific details.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was a bug in one release of beta software and is unlikely to be relevant to anyone in the future

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a bug that got fixed.

One of the issue tickets that was raised: [Unexcepted paste behaviour under multi cursor #181486](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/181486).

Pull Request with the fix: [Paste should insert text at all selection locations #181558](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/181558).

So just wait a little bit for  VS Code Insiders to update.

As a temporary workaround, you could try manually typing the content that you wanted to paste. Since your cursor positions you want to target are all before identical text, you could also work with that with find and replace: find the "here", and then replace with "<paste-content>here". If you need to restrict the replacement text, you can select the section containing what you want to replace and use the "find in selection" toggle.

For your reference / learning purposes, the above info was found simply by googling "`github vscode issues insiders 1.79 multicursor paste not working`".

Comment: It is working now with insiders version 1.79.0